# How to deal with Fragment Instance Variables when process death occurs

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm following this Medium Article on using fragments with BottomNavigationView:

https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711

but the author doesn't go into how to deal with it when Process Death occurs. What am I supposed to do with all the fragment Instance Variables? Because I am getting null pointers when returning to the app after process death.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Fragment currentBottomNavFragment;
    private FragmentHome fragmentHome;
    private FragmentSearch fragmentSearch;
    private FragmentProfile fragmentProfile;
}
```

**Edit 1:______________________________**

```
case R.id.bottomnav_home:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: " + fragmentHome);
                        fragmentHome = (FragmentHome) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_HOME");
                        if (fragmentHome == null) {
                            fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .add(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragmentHome, "FRAGMENT_HOME")
                                    .commit();
                        }else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: Fragment home not null");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: " + fragmentHome);
                        }

                        return true;
```

When I simulate process death and click on the home navigation view, the first log.d

```
Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: " + fragmentHome);
```

[image]

returns a null fragmentHome, however the if else statement is going to the else meaning the fragmentHome is not null. Why am I getting this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment manager has a `putFragment` and `getFragment` method you can use to save and restore instance state of your Fragments.

This allowed me to save my Fragment Instance Variables so they didn't return null after process death.

Answer (score 0):

The safe way to handle this scenario is to try to get the Fragment by its unique tag, before trying to add it yourself.

```
fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("someTag");
if(fragment == null) {
    fragment = new MyFragment();
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(fragment, R.id.container, "someTag");
}
```

Comment: I am getting a weird issue when simulating process death using the red button check my edit above